# Proliant gen6 drive cage kit on a gen8 ml350e

Tags: hpe

Does anyone know if a gen6 LFF hot plug drive kit HP - 487737-B21 will fit in a proliant ml350e gen8 (gen8 equivalent part HP 659485-B21)? I know the caddy's are different across these generations, but the question is if the whole cage itself could be transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if a gen6 LFF hot plug drive kit HP - 487737-B21 will fit in a proliant ml350e gen8 (gen8 equivalent part HP 659485-B21)? I know the caddy's are different across these generations, but the question is if the whole cage itself could be transferred

It won't.